# Scrape specific data from a Deliveroo site

Tags: regex, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I would like to pull all ingredients that are unavailable (they still visible but in grey: an example with the

[image: drink] on a Deliveroo page.

All ingredients are on a

[image: pop up menu].

I would like to get a google sheet with all missing items per day.
Does anyone have an idea of how to build that?

The link to the Deliveroo page is:
https://deliveroo.co.uk/menu/london/soho/honi-poke?day=today&postcode=W1T1DE&time=ASAP

Comment: You might want to remove that Google Drive link, as thousands (or more) people may read this question and click through to it.  Instead, please add all relevant data directly into your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(IMPORTDATA(
 "https://deliveroo.co.uk/menu/london/soho/honi-poke?day=today&postcode=W1T1DE&time=ASAP#"),
 "select Col1 where Col1 contains'item--unavailable'"),
 "\>|\<|\/|\""", ""), "0.1(.*)spanh6"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working for a for the items on the website. Is it possible to have it also on the pop up menu, where we can select items ( second image).

Comment: what do I need to add for the pop up menu?